# How can an input field be formatted to Currency syntax?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to have an input field that checks to make sure the **user input** is formatted in US currency, and if it isn't, throw an error.

The way I see this being accomplished in SAPUI5 is utilizing the 'Currency' data type or creating a Formatter function. Here is an example of its syntax:

```
<Input id="inp1" 
   value="{
   path: '/price',
   type:'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
 }" />
```

The issue I have with this solution is that in all the data type examples I have seen, the 'path' field always connects to a model. Since this is a user input, I don't need to hookup to the model, nor do I want to. How can I format and/or validate the input value to display in proper Currency format without creating a path to the model?

Comment: What are you doing with the user input?

Comment: the user input is simply acting as a search field